# How to send mail in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I have heroku account and setup the app on heroku

Site is working fine but only mail functionality not working i have do the following code.

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def sample_email()

    email = 'to@gmail.com'
    recipient = 'rec@gmail.com'
    subject = 'This is tesing '
    message = 'This is dummy mail'

    Emailer.deliver_contact(recipient, subject, message)
    return if request.xhr?
    render :text => 'Message sent successfully'

  end
end
```

Comment: you can google around and will get many answers....just setup smtp as you need to SEND email and rest of the stuff is handled by rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setup mailer to send emails**

in app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Mailer
  default from: "no-reply@myapp.com"

def welcome(user_email)
   @user=User.find_by_email user_email
   Rails.logger.info "==========sending welcome email to ==> #{@user.email}"
   mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Hi #{@user.username},Welcome to #{configatron.app_name}")
end
 end
```

**setup view file to send as email**

```
app/views/user_emailer/welcome.html.erb

<p>Hi <%= @user.username %>,Welcome to myapp.com</p>
```

**setup email configurations**

in config/initializers/email_setup.rb

```
if Rails.env != 'test'
  email_settings = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/email.yml"))
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = email_settings[Rails.env] unless email_settings[Rails.env].nil?
end
```

**setup keys/passwords,using gmail..for development but use mailchimp/mandrill for pro**

```
in config/email.yml

    development:
      :address: smtp.gmail.com
      :port: 587
      :authentication: plain
      :user_name: milind@gmail.com
      :password: password
      :enable_starttls_auto: true
    production:
      :address: smtp.gmail.com
      :port: 587
      :authentication: plain
      :user_name: milind@gmail.com
      :password: password
      :enable_starttls_auto: true
```

**user mailer to send email**

```
UserMailer.welcome(current_user).deliver
```

HOPE IT HELPS.... :)